# What are the commands to conduct DWH test and overidentifying restrictions tests when dealing with panel data?

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

All the ressources I find on the internet show me how to conduct a Durbin-Wu Hausman test and an overidentifying restrictions test on cross-sectional data.

How could I do these tests in R with fixed effects/random effects regressions obtained with the `plm` package?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is implemented in package `plm` with the `phtest` function. The package's vignette even has a section about it: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/A_plmPackage.html

```
library(plm)
data("Gasoline", package = "plm")
form <- lgaspcar ~ lincomep + lrpmg + lcarpcap
wi <- plm(form, data = Gasoline, model = "within")
re <- plm(form, data = Gasoline, model = "random")
phtest(wi, re)
## 
##  Hausman Test
## 
## data:  form
## chisq = 302.8, df = 3, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
## alternative hypothesis: one model is inconsistent
```

Comment: I think that's what's confusing me. With cross-sectionnal data, the Hausman test is used to test the consistency of two stage least squares. But with panel data, that very same test is used to test which is the better model between fixed and random effects.

If I use the phtest command with a Pooled OLS model and a Fixed Effect IV model, will it test whether 2SLS is consistent ? Or am I using the wrong command if what I want to test is the consistency of 2SLS ?

In the vignette you linked, they are only talking about FE vs. RE, so I'm not sure if phtest can be used in the context of IV

Comment: Your underlying question seems to be a statistical one, not a programming question. Statistical questinos are on topic on Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/, but off topic on Stackoverflow.